# if object collides with the same object

Tags: java, arraylist, libgdx, collision

i cant figure out how to make a collision with the same object from the same ArrayList, BUT not itself in lbgdx. Is it even possible? And how do I do that?

How I create objects:

```
private static List<Tree> objects = new ArrayList<Tree>();


for (int i = 0; i<400 ; i++ ) {
        objects.add(new Tree());
        }
```

They spawn randomly around the "player" and sometimes they're on top each other.

Tree class:

```
public class Tree {
public TextureRegion sprite;
public Vector2 position;
private int x, y, varx, vary;
public int size;
private Random r;
public boolean injunglex, injungley = false;
public int myLevel;
public Rectangle objrect, objrectUP;
public Rectangle playerrect;
public boolean active = false;
private int random, tolis=700;
public Tree() {
    GameRender.medis++;
    size = GameRender.tilesize*5;
    position = new Vector2(x, y);
    r = new Random();
    random = r.nextInt(2);
    int zenkas = r.nextInt(2);
    if(AssetLoader.load){
    position.y = AssetLoader.getInt("treey"+GameRender.medis);
    position.x = AssetLoader.getInt("treex"+GameRender.medis);  
    }else{
        position.y = getPositionY();
        position.x = getPosition();     
    while(position.y>GameRender.playery-100&&position.y<GameRender.playery+100
            &&position.x>GameRender.playerx-100&&position.x<GameRender.playerx+100){
        position.y = getPositionY2();
        position.x = getPosition2();
       }
    }
}
public int getPosition() {
    int x;
    int zenkasx = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam2;
    if(renkam==1){renkam=r.nextInt(50); renkam2=0;} else {renkam=0; renkam2=r.nextInt(50);}
    if(zenkasx==0){
        x = GameRender.playerx+renkam+(r.nextInt(tolis));
    }else x = GameRender.playerx-renkam2-(r.nextInt(tolis));
    return x;
}
public int getPosition2() {
    int x;
    int zenkasx = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam2;
    if(renkam==1){renkam=0; renkam2=+r.nextInt(100);} else {renkam=r.nextInt(100); renkam2=0;}
    if(zenkasx==0){
        x = GameRender.playerx+renkam+(r.nextInt(tolis));
    }else x = GameRender.playerx-renkam2-(r.nextInt(tolis));
    return x;
}
public int getPositionY() {
    int x;
    int zenkasx = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam2;
    if(renkam==1){renkam=r.nextInt(50); renkam2=0;} else {renkam=0; renkam2=r.nextInt(50);}
    if(zenkasx==0){
        x = GameRender.playery+renkam+(r.nextInt(tolis));
    }else x = GameRender.playery-renkam2-(r.nextInt(tolis));
    return x;
}
public int getPositionY2() {
    int x;
    int zenkasx = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam = r.nextInt(2);
    int renkam2;
    if(renkam==1){renkam=100; renkam2=+r.nextInt(200);} else {renkam=r.nextInt(200); renkam2=100;}
    if(zenkasx==0){
        x = GameRender.playery+renkam+(r.nextInt(tolis/3));
    }else x = GameRender.playery-renkam2-(r.nextInt(tolis/3));
    return x;
}
private TextureRegion getSprite() {
    int medis = r.nextInt(3)+1;
         if(medis==1) sprite = AssetLoader.tree1;
    else if(medis==2) sprite = AssetLoader.tree2;
    else if(medis==3) sprite = AssetLoader.tree3;
    return sprite;
} 
public void createMe() {
    GameRender.batch.draw(sprite, position.x, position.y, size, size);  
}
```

}

Comment: What does the Tree's equals method look like?

Comment: added tree class if that's what you were asking

Comment: I want to know is there is a way to create a rectangle around a tree and if the rectange overlaps the other tree same rectangle: do something.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (If you wanted to know *how* to do it, then ask that.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear

> I want to know is there is a way to create a rectangle around a tree and if the rectange overlaps the other tree same rectangle: do something.

But I will do the best I can:

You could just create two boxes about the tree. You would do that by checking something like `if (object.box() overlaps otherObject.box())`

However, you could also have a far more detailed collision box by using a `double[][][]` and then storing it with the coordinate.

Basically, you would put the coordinates in the `double[][][]`, and then you could check if the other tree is within that `double[][][]`, and if it is, then they have collided.
You could set a 1 for a coordinate, and a 0 for air.

So for example, `if (double[treeX][treeY][treeZ] == 1) do collision stuff here.`